# How to style SVG shadow root in Chrome?

Tags: css, svg, shadow-dom

I've recently finished up a website and it's running nicely in Firefox. Chrome has problems with the SVG elements on my site however.

This is how I display SVGs on my site. With -use- it's basically treated like inline SVG, but it doesn't clutter my HTML with vector data and can be stowed away nicely in an external file.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 120 120"><use xlink:href="img/skills.svg#De"></use></svg>
```

This is one of the icons in my SVG file.

```
<g id="De">
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#90938F" stroke-width="19"/>
    <circle class="SKlevel" cx="60" cy="60" r="50" fill="none"/>
    <path d="M60 10.2C38.4 10.2 20.1 23 13.1 43h93.9C99.9 23 81.6 10.2 60 10.2z"/>
    <path d="M10 59.8C10 66 11.1 72 13.2 77h93.6c2.1-5 3.2-11 3.2-17.2 0-6-1.1-11.8-3-16.8h-93.9C11.1 48 10 53.8 10 59.8z" fill="#FC0000"/>
    <path d="M60 109.4c21.4 0 39.7-13.4 46.8-32.4H13.2C20.3 96 38.6 109.4 60 109.4z" fill="#FC0"/>
  </g>
```

This is the styling for the 'progress bars' that wrap around the icons.

```
.SKlevel
{
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    stroke: #2E8B57;
    stroke-width: 20px;
    stroke-dasharray: 316;
}
```

And this is to set the progress to a specific level which I have outsurced from my main CSS for ease of use.

```
#De > .SKlevel
{
    stroke-dashoffset: 30;
}
```

This is what an icon on my site looks like.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq832.jpg

Chrome doesn't accept the styling of the external 'SKlevel' class like Firefox does and I can't seem to figure out how to style anything in the shadow root. It doesn't work on other classes or IDs either.

Comment: What is your browser version?

Comment: 56.0.2 - Firefox, 62.0.3202.89 - Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I can see that it works in Firefox, it is in violation of the [spec](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/struct.html#UseStyleInheritance):

> ...elements in the shadow tree inherit styles from its host ‘use’ element, but...style rules defined in the outer document do not match the elements in the shadow tree.

**This should not work.**

A standard-conformant version should have the stylesheet with the `.SKlevel` selector as part of the skills.svg file. Unfortunately, the stylesheet seems not to be applied to externally re-used elements. Again, the spec is not implemented - in this case both by Firefox and Chrome. I got it only to work if the style was stated as a style attribute directly on the `<circle>` element. If every icon shows the same "progress" ring, you can avoid repeating it for each of them like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <circle id="progress" cx="60" cy="60" r="50" fill="none"  transform="rotate(-90 60 60)"
            style="stroke:#2E8B57;stroke-width:20;stroke-dasharray:316;"/>
  </defs>
  <g id="De">
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#90938F" stroke-width="19"/>
    <use xlink:href="#progress" />
    <path d="M60 10.2C38.4 10.2 20.1 23 13.1 43h93.9C99.9 23 81.6 10.2 60 10.2z"/>
    <path d="M10 59.8C10 66 11.1 72 13.2 77h93.6c2.1-5 3.2-11 3.2-17.2 0-6-1.1-11.8-3-16.8h-93.9C11.1 48 10 53.8 10 59.8z" fill="#FC0000"/>
    <path d="M60 109.4c21.4 0 39.7-13.4 46.8-32.4H13.2C20.3 96 38.6 109.4 60 109.4z" fill="#FC0"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Then, you can apply the `stroke-dashoffset` to the `<use>` element. It will be inherited by each element in the shadow tree, but since only the one `<circle>` element (in the second-level shadow tree) has a `stroke-dasharray`, it has no effect on any other element:

```
<style>
.SKDe {
    stroke-dashoffset: 30;
}
</style>
<svg viewBox="0 0 120 120"><use class="SKDe" xlink:href="img/skills.svg#De"></use></svg>
```

Comment: So I've stumbled across the opposite of _'It's not a bug, it's a feature'_ here. Your solution works fine however. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see why you think there's a Firefox bug here. Use points to the id="De" element and that's cloned so the styling should apply.

Comment: @RobertLongson Have one file index.html with a style element containing all styles listed by the OP, and the <use> element referencing an external file skills.svg. Have another file skills.svg containing the <g id="De"> element, but no styling. Styles from the index.html style element should not be applicable to the elements in the shadow tree inside the use element, but are in Firefox: https://browser-unplugged.net/games/temp/index.html

Comment: No, per [SVG2](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/struct.html#UseElement) In addition, all style rules that apply in the scope of the referenced element also apply in the scope of the cloned shadow tree.

Comment: I'm taking this to a bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1417085

Answer (score -1):

work in chrome:

css:

```
:root{
   --color1: #f00;
   --color2: #0f0;
}
path#icon1 {
    fill: var(--color1);
}
path#icon2 {
    fill: var(--color2);
}
```

html:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path id="icon1" d="M 0 0, 100 0, 100 50, 0 50, Z" />
    <path id="icon2" d="M 50 0, 100 50, 100 100, 0 100, Z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Your example doesn't include any shadowDOM e.g introduced by a `<use>`  element.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).